# How to use SimplePie with Laravel

Tags: laravel, simplepie

I am using Laravel 5.2. I need to get RSS feeds using SimplePie, so I install the library through composer.json and now my vendor folder contains simplepie but when i run the following code this error shows:

> ErrorException in SimplePie.php line 1379: ./cache is not writeable.
>   Make sure you've set the correct relative or absolute path, and that
>   the location is server-writable.

My code in route:

```
Route::get('feed', function () {

$feed = new SimplePie();

$feed->set_feed_url(array(
    'http://www.thenews.com.pk/rss/2/16' //it has no images
));
$feed->init();
$itemCount=$feed->get_item_quantity();
return $itemCount;
});
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried to resolve the error yourself?

Comment: Error looks simple enough.

Comment: Add "Pie" to the title of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a writeable cache folder for simplepie in the /storage/ folder (I called mine simplepie_cache).

Set the path in your feed object:

$feed->set_cache_location(storage_path() . '/simplepie_cache');

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

check what is saying `./cache is not writeable` can't write to cache folder check permissions to this folder or try a L5 wrapper for SimplePie `https://github.com/willvincent/feeds`